# Programmatically creating scrollview(s) from custom component in android

Tags: android, custom-component, scrollview

I'm trying to build a compound control in Android, containing (among other things) a ScrollView. Things go wrong when I try to view the control in Eclipse, crashing with a NullPointerException after the error message: "Parser is not a BridgeXmlBlockParser".

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1720)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:277)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:83)
at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:128)
at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:124)
at android.widget.ScrollView.<init>(ScrollView.java:120)
at my.compound.control.StringPicker.onMeasure(StringPicker.java:46)
...
```

I've traced the error to the following conditions:

- The NPE is thrown because a `Context.obtainStyledAttributes()` call returns `null` when the `attrs` argument passed is `null`.
- This only applies to the `BridgeContext` implementation used in Eclipse, which expects `attrs` to be an instance of the `BridgeXmlBlockParser`.
- The `attrs` argument is `null` because I create the ScrollView using the (Context) constructor.

There is a workaround of course, which is passing the `attrs` I receive when Eclipse constructs the compound control, but I don't want all the attributes set on the compound control to apply to my inner control.

Am I doing something wrong, is this a bug in Android Eclipse, ...?

This is what my.compound.control.StringPicker.onMeasure looks like (stripped it a bit for clarity):

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (this.getChildCount() != requestedLength) {
        this.removeAllViews();
        int childWidth = getWidth() / requestedLength;
        int childHeight = getHeight();
        for (int i = 0; i < requestedLength; i++) {
            ScrollView child = new ScrollView(getContext()); // NPE here
            child.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(childWidth, childHeight));
            addView(child);
        }
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Comment: Would you show us how did you built it in my.compound.control.StringPicker.onMeasure ? Otherwise, we can't say what's wrong.

Comment: I've added it, hope that helps :)

Comment: Which line is 46? And if you stripped things out, we may not be able to see what is wrong.

Comment: Line 46 is the call to the ScrollView constructor, I will mark it with a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to have been a bug in older Android versions.

The problem does not appear in Android version 2.3 or higher, but does appear when selecting Android 2.2 or lower. The workaround for these older Android versions is (as mentioned in the question) to copy the `attrs` parameter from the constructor.
This is only needed if you want to use design-view in Eclipse with these older versions, to run your application in the older versions no workaround is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

How are you creating your compound control, via XML layout or dynamically in the code?
A possible reason I could think of is that you are adding it via XML but you may not have added the StringPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) constructor. There you should call super(context, attrs).

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what I mention as a workaround. But there is no need to apply any (XML-)attributes to the contained component, I want to specify those in code.